# Removing a database row via the C# DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, datagridview

In a .NET 3.5 winforms application I have a `DataGridView` component that uses a `TableAdapter` to a MySQL database.

I am able to add a new record by adding code to the `BindingSource_AddingNew` event.

```
private void someBindingSource_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow ThisDataRow = ((DataRowView)((BindingSource)sender).Current).Row;
    if (ThisDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
    {
        someTableAdapter.Insert(ThisDataRow.ItemArray[1].ToString());
    }
}
```

and I am able to update a record by adding code to the `BindingSource_CurrentItemChanged` event.

```
private void someBindingSource_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow ThisDataRow = ((DataRowView)((BindingSource)sender).Current).Row;
    if (ThisDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
    {
        someTableAdapter.Update(ThisDataRow);
    }
}
```

How do I handle a delete event?

** UPDATE 1 **

To handle a delete event a button was added (you need to select the row before pressing the button):

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 selectedRowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
        if (selectedRowCount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
            {
                    //delete from database
                    someTableAdapter.Delete(Convert.ToUInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Index].Cells[0].Value));
                    //refresh datagridview
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Index);

             }
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [DataGridView.UserDeletingRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) event.

```
private void DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // It is a cancellable event, you could cancel the delete on certain conditions.
    e.Cancel = true;

}
```

Comment: @Hiremath - You are correct for removing the row from the datagridview.  I updated my answer to show how it was possible to remove the record from the underlying database also.