# How to delete selected row on datagridview and that also reflects to the database?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am working with C# Window Form, I have created a form connect to mySQL database and it display list of databases, list of tables on each database and also tables contents of each table.

Questions that I have here:

1. After I selected a random cell in the table (datagridview) and click Delete button, I want that row (corresponding to the selected cell) to be deleted on the database.
2. I also need that the datagridview table content also will be refreshed and updated (with that row has been removed). (This part I think I can do if I know how to do the part 1)

So I need help with the question 1, one of those things I can't not figure out is that how can I write the SQL statement to put in the SQLadapter or SQLcommandbuilder or whatever it is. I know the SQL statement should be like:

Delete from (selected Table) Where (**THIS IS THE PART WHERE I STUCK AT**) => I dont know what to put in this condition, how to get it?

Any helps and advises is really appreciated!

Comment: Have you used databinding? Are you using `MySqlDataAdapter`?

Comment: How the Delete SQL statement should be, can you help me?

Comment: In the `WHERE` part must be a Primary Key, for example the column `OrderNum` is a PK

Comment: That thing I know but HOW can I write it in the code, notice I am working with different data, in different tables (when I click to a particular table in the table list) so is there any flexible way to do that. IF I ONLY WORKING WITH ONE TABLE THAT MAY NOT BE A PROBLEM?

Comment: Why in WHERE part must be a primary key, I thought it could be anything????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete statement should consider all the selected table primary key columns and the selected row from the datagridview.

How to get the primary key columns:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
 FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbName')
  AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'tableName')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI');
```

Source: [A better way to get Primary Key columns](http://mysql-0v34c10ck.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/better-way-to-get-primary-key-columns.html)

How your delete statement should look like:

```
DELETE FROM <TABLE> 
  WHERE <PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_1> = <ROW_VALUE_1>
    AND <PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_2> = <ROW_VALUE_2>
```

You see, the table could have multiple columns uniquely identifying a row. There is also the possibility of existing a reference for that very row on another table, which would prevent you from deleting it.

It would look like this:

```
List<string> primaryKeyColumns = GetPrimaryKeyColumns(SelectedDB, SelectedTable);
string deleteWhereClause = string.Empty;
foreach (string column in primaryKeyColumns)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = datagridview.CurrentCell.OwningRow;
    string value = row.Cells[column].Value.ToString();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(deleteWhereClause))
    {
        deleteWhereClause = string.Concat(column, "=", value);
    }
    else 
    {

        deleteWhereClause += string.Concat(" AND ", column, "=", value);
    }
}
string deleteStatement = string.Format("DELETE FROM {0} WHERE {1}", SelectedTable, deleteWhereClause);
```

The method `GetPrimaryKeyColumns` returns the names of all the primary key columns of the selected table using the select statement i posted.
You would also have to deal with other types of columns such as dates and strings, but that's basically what you will have.

Comment: I don't worry about the referential integrity constraint violation here because I will put the code in the try{}catch tag, so if there is any errors it will not doing anything. My main problem here I still don't know how to write the SQL query for the deletion, Delete from (selected table) Where (what is in here)?????

Comment: That's what i tried to explain. You have to get the primary key column names and get the respective values from the selected row, then you build the delete where clause. Firstly, are you aware of primary keys?

Comment: Ok I don't know yet but probably I should aware of primary keys because anyway I must find these keys to put in the WHERE clause of delete query. So yes you was right, Let's do: 1. Find the primary keys 2. Get the values of those keys => these are 2 things I want to ask, please advise me, what function or statement I should look at?

Comment: Hey I also find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343222/removing-a-database-row-via-the-c-sharp-datagridview?rq=1 but not sure what is the ...someTableAdapter.Delete.... , can some one explain?

Comment: Updated the answer with some basic code of how it would look like.

Comment: Hi there I can't figure out how to do the GetPrimaryKeyColumns() method to make it returns string[], please advise.

Comment: Do you know how to execute a SELECT statement on the database?